# Using OAuth in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth, oauth-2.0

So far I've seen 2 ways of using OAuth in Spring security, one is the filter approach, as in https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/ and the other one is through configuring `HttpSecurity`, as in http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-oauth2-login

I wonder what's the difference/relation between these 2 methods?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The first one is part of Spring Security OAuth2 project and the second one is part of Spring Security 5.x project. That are two different projects.

Comment: 2 approaches doing the same thing?

Comment: There is always another way to do the same thing.